# In sympy, evaluating an expression using .subs() when that expression has been defined in another function

Tags: python, sympy, substitution, evaluation

If I define a symbolic expression inside a function, how do I evaluate that expression using `.subs()` outside that function. The following code demonstrates the issue:

```
import sympy as sp

def myFun():
    x = sp.symbols("x", positive = True)
    y = 3*x

    return y

expr = myFun()
print(expr.subs({x:10}))
```

Running the code above gives `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`.

How can I perform this evaluation? Two things I could think of is declaring `x` to be a global variable using `global x` inside `myFun()`. However, I want to avoid this method. Another way is to `lambdify` the expression in `myFun()` before returning the expression. But I would prefer not to use this method because in the real problem I am working with, I have multiple variables in my expression and would like to substitute only some of the variables at one stage, and the remaining variables at a later stage. Would you adopt one of the two approaches I mentioned or is it possible to evaluate the expression using `.subs()` using some other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@cards answer is not going to work, the reason is that you have defined `x` to be positive, instead when calling  `print(expr.subs({'x':10}))` the string `'x'` will generate a generic symbol, without assumptions.

You either create your symbols outside of the function, like this:

```py
import sympy as sp

x = sp.symbols("x", positive = True)
def myFun():
    y = 3*x
    return y

expr = myFun()
print(expr.subs({x:10}))
# out: 30
```

Or you can retrieve the symbols that make up a symbolic expression with the `free_symbol` attribute, like this:

```py
import sympy as sp

def myFun():
    x = sp.symbols("x", positive = True)
    y = 3*x
    return y

expr = myFun()
x = expr.free_symbols.pop()
print(expr.subs({x:10}))
# out: 30
```

**EDIT (to accommodate comment)**:

> I was just wondering but what if the expression had three variables, say `5*y + 3*x + 7*z`? I tried the code you provided. The line `expr.free_symbols.pop()` only gives one of the variables - it gives `x`. Is there a way to use `free_symbols` to get all three variables?

`free_symbols` returns a set with all variables. If the expression is `expr = 5*y + 3*x + 7*z`, then `expr.free_symbols` returns `{x, y, z}`.

`pop()` is a method of Python's `set`: it returns the first element of a set.

To get all the variables of your expression you could try: `x, y, z = expr.free_symbols`, or `x, y, z = list(expr.free_symbols)`. However, this creates the following problem: execute `print(x, y, z)` and you'll get something similar to: `y z x`. In other words, **the symbols returned by `expr.free_symbols` are unordered**. This is the default Python behavior.

Can we get ordered symbols? Yes, we can sort them alphabetically with : `x, y, z = sorted(expr.free_symbols, key=str)`. If we now execute `print(x, y, z)` we will get `x y z`.

Comment: nice `free_symbols.pop`!

Comment: I was just wondering but what if the expression had three variables, say `5*y + 3*x + 7*z`? I tried the code you provided. The line `expr.free_symbols.pop()` only gives one of the variables - it gives `x`. Is there a way to use `free_symbols` to get all three variables?

Comment: Updated answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

`x` as a `Symbol` object is only declared in the function's body, so it's not accessible from the outside. Use `'x'` as a string.

```
x = list(expr.free_symbols)[0]
print(expr.subs({x: 2}))
```

Comment: This won't work if the symbol in the expression has non-default assumptions (i.e. `positive=True`).

Comment: mmm I will look at it (I tested without the constraint)

Comment: `x` as a string will fix `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`. To perform the substitution you will need the `free_symbols` attribute (because `x` is declared as a `Symbol` with constraint/assumption)

Answer (score 0):

Let's create an expression with two symbols in it:

```
In [44]: x, y = symbols('x, y')

In [45]: expr = sin(y) + x**2
```

Suppose that we only have the expression as a local variable. We can find the symbols it contains using `free_symbols`. We can use that to build a dict that maps symbol names (as strings) to the symbols themselves:

```
In [46]: expr.free_symbols
Out[46]: {x, y}

In [47]: syms = {s.name: s for s in expr.free_symbols}

In [48]: syms
Out[48]: {'y': y, 'x': x}
```

This mapping is important because different symbols with the same names but different assumptions are not interchangeable. With that we can substitute the symbol whose name is `'x'` like this:

```
In [49]: expr.subs(syms['x'], 2)
Out[49]: sin(y) + 4
```